# Determine where is the first zero in a float number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, floating-point

In my app I have a few random float numbers. I have to determine, where does the period of zero's start to cut the number and display it in an UILabel.

So, for example, if I have number 3.05 it is displayed as 3.0500000 while I want it to be displayed properly '3.05'.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your existing code, so the answers can be specific to what you already are doing?

Comment: It won't always end in zeros, or even in anything in particular. You could get, for example, 1.999999998 or something. Use format specifiers, like Dean says.

Comment: @Jesse Rusak I need to get rid of the zeros only...

Comment: Knodel - I think you might be surprised how many floating point numbers aren't quite the number you expect them to be :) I hadn't even considered errors in my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use length limitation like @"%.2f".  But i think if you want to rim zeroes you should use this:

```
NSString* string = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", 3.05000000] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"0"]];
```

Will return 3.05

```
NSString* string = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", 3.0500100000] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"0"]];
```

Will return 3.05001  while @"%.2f" will return 3.05

You should notice the rounding errors, so for number 3.0500000010000 the string 3.05 would be returned.

Comment: I think your answer might be better than mine :(

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I've been looking for

Answer (score 2):

Use the [format specifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) :

```
// Print max two numbers after the decimal point
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", number];
```

---

If you need to work out the position of the first 0, render it to a string and then search that string for the first '0'

```
// Render the complete string
NSString *completeNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", number];

// Get the first 0
NSRange range = [completeNumber rangeOfString:@"0"];

// Trim the string
NSString myString = [completeNumber substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, range.location)];
```

Comment: See my example to trim to the first '0' however, Max has a good answer using `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` which I think might be better!

Comment: Thank you! However, Max's answer is better for me :)

Comment: Well, it is a better answer ;)

Comment: `NSRangeMake` should be `NSMakeRange`.

Comment: oops - I was typing from memory!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
NSString* myNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", number];
```

with 2 digits:

```
@"%.02f" = 3.05
```

with 3 digit:

```
@"%.03f" = 3.050
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how many digits I need -  the numbers are different each time.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your question: There aren't repeating zeroes in that float. More specifically, the floating-point representation of 3.05 is not actually equal to 3.05 — it's actually more like 3.04999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875. Your best bet if this is important would be to use something like NSDecimalNumber and its string conversion methods. It can precisely represent base-10 numbers, unlike binary floating-point.

Comment: Even with a 64 bit floating point number, you only get 17 significant digits.  But I do understand that you were using hyperbole to make a valid point.